# How to link to a comment?

Tags: support, comment, hyperlinks

I was wondering if it is possible to link to a comment? For example, the second comment after this reply [Questions about geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/questions-about-geometric-distribution/26412#26412)

Thanks!

Comment: It is not obvious from UX, See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links

Answer (score 11):

You can obtain links to comments by clicking on the time of the comment posting, which appears right after the name of user who posted it.  (Looking at the [recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/152579) in the [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436/155585) that [Hendrik's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1818/1424) links to, this appears to be a new feature.)

Another way is to find the comment in the activity tab of the user who posted it, and click the link there.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this question on meta.SO: [How to link to a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436/155585) I don't know, however, if the solutions provided in the answers still work.

Comment: Thanks! I read the discussion, but still can't find out the link for a comment that I want to link.