# Possibility to copy content of comment that was posted longer than 5 minutes ago.

Tags: feature-request, comment

I sometimes write a comment which I realize would fit better as an edit, adding context or examples or better explanations to a question or answer. Or for that matter to make an edit with the content based on someone elses comment.

Then I would want to copy the content of the comment MathJax code and paste it in the edit.

Is there some way to do this now? If not, then I think maybe it could be a good feature.

---

Also: feel free to edit my tags as I am not as familiar with meta's tags as I am with math.SE.

Comment: Right-click on the formula and "Show Math As -> TeX Commands"?

Comment: Oh you are right. How ignorant of me, is it a feature of MathJax? I have been going along manually copying pasting all the time.

Comment: Yes, the context menu is a MathJax feature. (There's other useful stuff there too.)

Comment: This seems to be rather similar question to this one: [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) I find especially the bookmarklet given there very useful. (Although it can only be used for copying comments on a question.)

Comment: And perhaps I should also add link to this meta.SE post: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390)