# Possibility to access the code of people's comments

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment, editing

Very often I enter the edit mode of a post just to copy-paste some parts of it, often to get a sample of some MathJax complex syntax.

It may happen every once in a while that you want to do that with a comment, except this is not possible unless you have moderation powers that allow you to edit comments. What's worse: $5$ minutes after posting you can't access the source code of *your own comments*.

So I know two possible ways around that,

- by right-clicking into the source code of the page itself and then `ctrl+F` the desired sequence,
- by first highlighting the sequence and then right-click "`show math as > TeX commands`", although this one works only for one line at a time.

But I really think that it would be appropriate and useful to have an implemented feature allowing a more direct way.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. Although it feels a bit weird to click "Thanks, that solved my problem", because it really doesn't, the accepted answer is what I already do and would like to avoid. But thanks. @user357151

Comment: Comments are deliberately light on features, ostensibly with the intent of limiting them to their intended purpose -- e.g. to discourage their use as a medium for discussion or for providing content -- so this is unlikely to change. (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Since you mention that you are not satisfied with the accepted answer in the currently chosen duplicate target: Did you look also at other answer and also at other posts linked there. In the comments, there is also link to the question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390)

Comment: Personally, I often use the bookmarklet linked [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment#16530) (see comments there for a working link) - although it only works for comment on a *question*; not for comments on answers. I will add also link to a related question on Meta MathOverflow (specifically because of the SEDE query linked there): [How to cut and paste](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3665)

Comment: @MartinSleziak It's *really sad* that the question is already closed, because the bookmarklet trick is brilliant, and I could have actually tried my hand on it to make your comment into an answer and accept it. That would have been awesome.

Comment: :-) then let's try and do that. Or, you could post the answer at the linked question...

Comment: A recent question has an answer which summarizes various methods to get text from a comment: [How to copy page content including all TeX commands](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35201).

Answer (score 2):

*Generated by @MartinSleziak's answer highlighted below.*

*Here is the relevant link: https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/*

*Simply click and drag the desired link to your bookmarks toolbar.*

---

It is a duplicate indeed. Although it feels a bit weird to click "Thanks, that solved my problem", because it really doesn't, the accepted answer is what I already do and would like to avoid. But thanks. @user357151 -- [Arnaud Mortier](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121045_28795)

Comments are deliberately light on features, ostensibly with the intent of limiting them to their intended purpose -- e.g. to discourage their use as a medium for discussion or for providing content -- so this is unlikely to change. (to the best of my knowledge) -- [Hurkyl](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121049_28795)

@Hurkyl Thanks, that makes sense. -- [Arnaud Mortier](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121059_28795)

Since you mention that you are not satisfied with the accepted answer in the currently chosen duplicate target: Did you look also at other answer and also at other posts linked there. In the comments, there is also link to the question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390) -- [Martin Sleziak](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121061_28795)

> Personally, I often use the bookmarklet linked [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment#16530) (see comments there for a working link) - although it only works for comment on a *question*; not for comments on answers. I will add also link to a related question on Meta MathOverflow (specifically because of the SEDE query linked there): [How to cut and paste](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3665) -- [Martin Sleziak](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121063_28795)

@MartinSleziak It's *really sad* that the question is already closed, because the bookmarklet trick is brilliant, and I could have actually tried my hand on it to make your comment into an answer and accept it. That would have been awesome. -- [Arnaud Mortier](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121069_28795)

:-) then let's try and do that. Or, you could post the answer at the linked question... -- [Simply Beautiful Art](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/possibility-to-access-the-code-of-peoples-comments#comment121081_28795)