# Copy my original MathJax from my comment into paste buffer?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment

How can I copy one of my comments which is MathJax format and paste it in the solution since nobody answered my question? I have developed the answer in a comment.

Comment: Do some suggestion from the previous questions about this work for you? For example: [Possibility to access the code of people's comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28795), [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3234).

Comment: iPhone is my device. I see no button for showing latex.  Do I need to drag out the mainframe? Due to health I prefer light weight device.

Comment: Also, I do not program my iPhone. I prefer not to program while focusing on math.  That is why I use category feature-request. So I see some avid programmers have solved it.  Integrate the solution.

Comment: If you do not find the existing solutions satisfactory, perhaps you can upvote the corresponding feature request on the main meta: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390) (It has bigger chance to be noticed - and to gain some support - there than on a per-site meta. But my guess would be that something like this does not have too high priority.)

Comment: Thanks. It recorded my upvote, but the counter did not increment.