# Can one no longer quote comment with the new design?

Tags: support, comment, hyperlinks

I've read a lot of negative reactions to the [now all-out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites?cb=1) so-called responsive design.

This question of mine I'm not sure if it belongs to [that thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live/29019) or not as a feature request or bug report, since I might be just missing something here. I apologize if this has already been addressed elsewhere before.

I remember previously (before the new theme) one can click on something around a comment and get a http link, so that one can quote that specific comment just like any posts or wikipedia or any webpage out there.

It is useful when having back-and-forth discussions so I wonder if this can still be done now.

Comment: Doesn't the date and time of each comment produce a link to that comment?

Comment: Like this one: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29201/can-one-no-longer-quote-comment-with-the-new-design#comment123845_29201

Comment: P.S. SE deliberately designs to discourage the use of comments for content, and you probably shouldn't rely on a comment persisting for any length of time. I think you can use chat rooms if you want to have a discussion that has a persistent log.

Comment: As far as I can tell - and Carl Mummert confirms this in the very first comment, clicking on the timestamp to get the link still works. This is the way described here: [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436). (And it is also linked in one of the answers to [How to link to a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1816)) (I suppose this is what you meant by "...one can click on something around a comment and get a http link".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just experimented and discovered that the time of posting display is a link to the specific comment. So you can obtain the URL by any of your favorite methods of doing so; e.g. in Chrome I can:

- Click on it, which will put the URL in the address bar
- Right click on it, and select "copy link address" (which I can then paste elsewhere)

(note: this post assumes you mean that you wish to obtain a link to the comment rather than to quote it)

Comment: Yeah as I suspected, I was being momentarily stupid as this has been exactly the same as before the new theme. Indeed all I wanted was to link but not really quote the comment as in let the system automatically display the linked comment.